# how to make listview to take its appropriate lenght without scroll

Tags: android, listview

i am creating a **custom dropdown**,where custom dropdown is created **using relative layout and listview**, on click of  relative layout i am making **listview to visible and gone**, so like this there are many dropdowns vertically one after the other. Without putting scrollview it works fine, Here the problem is if i apply **scrollview** to whole layout **dropdown(which is made using listview)** will take only some space and inside the listview itself it enables scroll inside that some space. But i want it to appear as it is without scrolling listview. How could i do this.Any help and suggestion are welcomed.

**without scroll view**

[image]

**with scroll view**

[image]

**here i want it to appaer as in without scrollview image ,even if i apply scroll view to whole layout(here whole layout contains number of dropdowns as in figure.)**

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutView"

            android:background="@drawable/customborder">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/Text"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/viewtext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-Select-"
                    android:textColor="#ff3333"
                    android:textSize="10dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/DropDownArrowIcon"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listViewborder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2AACFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0.5dp">
            <ListView
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#57585B"
                android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="Type of bussinness"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bankInvesttxt"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/layoutView"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/bankInvestTextlayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bankInvestviewtext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-Select-"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="10dip" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bankInvestimageView"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/DropDownArrowIcon"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bankInvestlistViewborder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2AACFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="0.5dp">
            <ListView
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/bankInvestlistView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#57585B"
                android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: 1. scrollview has only one child. 2. scrollview has focus for scrolling listview dont.

Comment: can you please explain in short

Comment: That will crash at runtime, scrollView can only have ONE direct child (you have 5). Anyway you can put a fixed height to the listView (at code so you can do math for the needed height)  or change the list with a LinearLayout.

Comment: @Nanoc   here i am applying scrollview to my whole layout. on click of relative layout ,linear layout containing listview with hide and show.see my updated  images in question

Comment: @Amit Vaghela see my updated question with images

Comment: @arun here i have not yet set any focus to listview ,and scroll contains many dropdowns.See my updated question with images

Comment: I still think my comment is right

Comment: yeah the scrollview is parent by default got focus for touch listener. child listview dont get touch listener. (scrollview has only one direct child****)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: layoutView onClick set visiblity as visible the listView and listview itemselected set visiblity as gone. (Do this for both dropdown)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-Select-"
                android:textColor="#ff3333"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listViewborder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2AACFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutView"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="0.5dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#57585B"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankInvesttxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Type of bussinness"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutView"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bankInvesttxt"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bankInvestTextlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bankInvestviewtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-Select-"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bankInvestimageView"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bankInvestlistViewborder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2AACFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"        
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:padding="0.5dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bankInvestlistView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#57585B"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```